# I would like to prevent removing a jquery ui tab

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

As said in the title I would like to prevent removing a jquery ui tab or at least asking a confirmation before.

I tried

```
$( "#tabs" ).bind( "tabsremove", function(event, ui) {
        var ok=confirm("Are you sure you want to close this tab ?");
        if (ok) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        };
     });
```

or

```
$( "#tabs" ).bind( "tabsremove", function(event, ui) {
        var ok=confirm("Are you sure you want to close this tab ?");
        if (ok) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        };
     });
```

But the question is asked after, and not before as I want.
Is this possible ?

Comment: are you trying to remove the confirmation prompt? sorry i cannot really understand what you mean in your question, so i want to ask you...

Comment: no i would like to ask the question before so if the answer is "no" the tab will not be removed and if it is yes it will be removed.

Comment: i dont get it so clearly but do you want to use OnLoad or OnClick?

Comment: well on click on ui-icon-circle-close

Answer (score 0):

Is this [what you mean?](http://jsfiddle.net/bldoron/aX289/)

```
$( "#tabs span.ui-icon-close" ).live( "click", function() {
        var ok=confirm("Are you sure you want to close this tab ?");
        if (ok) {
            var index = $( "li", $tabs ).index( $( this ).parent() );
            $tabs.tabs( "remove", index );
        } else {
            return false;
        };
```

This is from [jQuery-ui-tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation)

Comment: You should put it in your `$(document).ready(function(){//put code here})`
If you want to give us some more code it would be nice. What's not working? Tried chrome developer tools to debug?

Comment: Thanks
i use chrome and i see that i have ui-icon-circle-close instead of ui-icon-close
Here [link]http://test03.christophe-charron.org/jquery/menu_00.php click on treeview "commandes" to add a tab